# Windows change DPI scaling programmatically without logging out

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, wmi

I've done a bunch of digging around on this and everything I've found indicates that to change the DPI scaling on Windows requires setting a registry value and then logging back in for the change to take effect.  However on a Windows Surface running Windows 10 Pro, you're able to do change the scaling without relogging.  Does anyone know how to change that programmatically/from the command line?

Registry key change method:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528846.aspx

Comment: Weird things happen when you change the DPI settings and don't log out and back in again.  Some applications respond OK, other don't.  Believe me - been there, done that.  But may I ask why are you trying to change the DPI setting anyway - that's a user preference that should be left to the user.

Comment: for testing purposes of an app to compare how the app handles different sizes

Comment: That would be a useful tool for my job as well. Send it over when you get it done. :)

Comment: I'll give you a reason -- to override a bad setting being fed in. I found this page looking for the solution for how to do it, with the sole intended purpose of writing a program that uses it via a hotkey.